# The <activity> element must be a direct child of the <application> element error

Tags: android, eclipse

I have added my third class to my package, and I want to add it to my androidmanifest.xml file. I  have added the second class easily with no problem, but I'm stuck with the third one.
When do I try to add the third activity:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.metoo.codedetective.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.metoo.codedetective.Etelaateomoomi">
        <activity android:name=".Factoryreset">

        </activity>

    </activity>            

</application>

</manifest>
```

I get The  element must be a direct child of the  element.
What should I do?
Please correct the code and post it.
thanks for advance

Comment: why do you want this: <activity android:name="com.metoo.codedetective.Etelaateomoomi">
        <activity android:name=".Factoryreset">

        </activity>

    </activity>

Comment: It's an activity in an activity

Comment: Activity in an activity is a bad idea, you go for fragments and the above is not the correct way, manifest is meant to list your classes, you can define the logical parent of an activity using parent tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
<activity android:name="com.metoo.codedetective.Etelaateomoomi">
    <activity android:name=".Factoryreset">

    </activity>

</activity>
```

remove `<activity android:name=".Factoryreset"> </activity>` because this is an activity in an activity which is not allowed.

I think you need this:

```
<activity android:name="com.metoo.codedetective.Etelaateomoomi.Factoryreset">

</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks for fast reply!

Comment: Always here @user3265515 :)

Comment: so when we are declaring an activity in android manifest we have to close it with an <activity> tag, right?

Comment: With the `<activity></activity>` tags, yeah

Comment: Thanks, I will set your answer the best in 8 minutes!

Comment: Hahahah ok @user3265515

Comment: I'm totally beginner I think :(

Comment: Ok ;)! I gave your answer the mark.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Always here @user3265515 :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following lines that represent an activity inside another activity.

```
<activity android:name=".Factoryreset">

</activity>
```